# How to push local code to new branch on gitlab . need specific steps (looks like a duplicate question but i need some specific steps)

Tags: git, gitlab, push, branch

I am newbie to gitlab. i have a git lab repository , I was asked to create a new branch and push code that i have(first time,i have code on my local pc).. I have verified lot of articles here and examples but not sure whehter i need all those different steps.

I have just gitbash installed on my pc and i have remote repository url and, have a folder where i have my code which needs to be added to that new branch

Can some one please help me setup steps please. My understanding i should perform below on my local pc is this correct ?

```
    git config --global user.name "your_username" 

    git config --global user.email "your_email_address@example.com"
   
    cd into directory where you have local code
    
    git clone https://gitlab.com/gitlab-tests/sample-project.git
    
    git init
    
    git remote add origin <git@gitlab.com:username/projectpath.git
    
    git checkout -b <name-of-branch>
    
    git checkout <name-of-branch>
    
    git add .
    git commit -m "COMMENT TO DESCRIBE THE INTENTION OF THE COMMIT"
    
    git push <remote> <name-of-branch>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need to do is this:

```
# This gets a copy of the remote repository to your PC (login will probably be required)
# Replace the URL with the actual URL of the repo
git clone https://gitlab.com/gitlab-tests/sample-project.git

# get into the repository (replace with the repository's name)
cd sample-project

# get your code where it should go
cp <where your local code is> <where it should be in the repo>

# Get to the branch (use the command that applies to your case!)
# Create a new branch if it does note exist on the remote
git checkout -b <branch-name>
# Check out the branch, if it already exists
git checkout <branch-name>

# Add the new code
git add .
git commit -m "<add a meaningful comment here>"

# Push the code to the remote repository (use the command that applies to your case!)
# like this if the branch does not exist on the remote
git push --set-upstream origin <branch-name>
# like this if the branch already exists on the remote
git push origin <branch-name>
```

Further notice:

- You should do the `git config` commands before, if you did not do that yet, but it is not required.
- `git init` will create a new repository which is not what you want to do. In case of gitlab, it will be done for you by gitlab.
- Usually, you not need to run `git remote add` yourself, if you clone from the correct URL.
- You need to use `git push --set-upstream` if your branch does not exist on the remote repository as you can see in my code.

Comment: Thank you very much for steps.  `# get your code where it should go
cp <where your local code is> <where it should be in the repo> ` this mean if i should copy the code to this sample project folder before pushing to gitlab ? I am bit confused about this `<where your local code is> <where it should be in the repo>`

Comment: exactly, the `git clone` will get you a repository that is exactly like the one on the server, there you do your changes (as in "add your code"), `git add` and `git commit` them and then push those changes to the remote. You will probably want to add your code do a directory in the repository, but that depends on what you are actually doing and on the structure of the repository.

Comment: To make it clear: you said, you had the code locally, so you copy it (that is what the `cp` command does) to the place in the repo you cloned. In the future, you can directly work on your repo.

Comment: thanks for clarification, ok so if i want to add my local files to a directory on repo, do i need to create that directory on gitlab console ? or can i create it from gitbash and push the code to that directory. for example in that sample folder project i have a directory called "sample" which has all the files, i wanted to push as "sample" directory to repository..sorry for so many silly question. trying to understand

Comment: just create it in the repository you cloned on the git bash (the command is probably `mkdir`). If you cloned your repo to `~/sample-project`, run `mkdir ~/sample-project/asp` to create the directory and then `cp /where/your/code/is ~/sample-project/asp`

Comment: It seems, you do not have too much experience with git. It will take some time to learn, but once you get it, it will be awesome ;) refer to [this e-book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) for first steps and to [this documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs) for specific commands.